# Sencha Touch Carousel optimization

Tags: dom, optimization, sencha-touch

I'm trying to optimize a Carousel component and I wanna have only one active item in DOM. It is easy to achieve simply by removing/adding components in the cardswitch event of carousel. But the problem is that my components load some ajax info from server before rendering and it takes time, so it's slow to rerender them on each cardswitch.

Is there any technique to cache created components but at the same time to not add them to DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way to keep items otside the DOM and then put them back, so the only solution I found is to recreate items when the became active. It's actually the way Sencha suggests.

The other interesting technique is the one Sencha implemented in ST2. It actually keeps only 3 items in DOM event if carousel has 100000 items. Check the html in Chrome. Haven't seen this carefully yet, but it's cool and performance is great.